# php_uname disabled error on checkout paypal

Tags: paypal

Getting error php_uname disabled after clicking to checkout. On main website all works well. I copied main site to as addon domain(new site) and now it gives me that error.

Host says that php_uname is disabled because of security problems. Anyways, how to bypass that php_uname as paypal works normally on main site which is hosted at same server and provider.

Answer (score 0):

Was just a bug in line of a code. Updated API and all worked well.